# Getting radio list from another class

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have a visual force page that uses a standard controller and I want to use another class on the same visual force page? How this can be achieved?

```
<apex:page standardController="Loan_Payment_Plan__c" extensions="PaymentPlanController" sideBar="false">

 <apex:pageBlockSection id="MutiplePaymentDetailBasedOnFrequency" rendered="{!shouldDisplayMultiDetailSection}">
            <apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ifScheduleMultiplePaymentDetails}"  >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!displayFrequencySection}" reRender="MutiplePaymentDetailBasedOnFrequency"/>
                <apex:outputLabel >Schedule Multiple Payment Details</apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="FrequencySection" rendered="{!displayFrequencySection}">
                <apex:selectRadio value="{!frequency}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!frequencyType}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The class file is

```
public with sharing class LoanPaymentPlanRecurringTask {

    String frequency = null;

    public List<SelectOption> getFrequencyType(){
        List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Daily','Daily'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Weekly','Weekly'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Monthly','Monthly'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Yearly','Yearly'));
        return options;
    }
    public String getFrequency(){
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String frequency){
        this.frequency=frequency;
    }
}
```

I want to add the above class file to my vf page so that my radio list can work and then I can add more functionalities. 
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

As this [Building a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) documentation illustrates, multiple (comma-separate) classes can be specified in the `extensions` attribute.

So in your case your would have:

```
extensions="PaymentPlanController, LoanPaymentPlanRecurringTask"
```

but you would need to add a constructor to `LoanPaymentPlanRecurringTask` that takes a standard controller:

```
public LoanPaymentPlanRecurringTask(ApexPages.StandardController sc) { }
```

Where the same property or method names exist in both classes, those from the left-most class win.

This approach keeps the classes independent and lets you add them - [compose](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CompositionInsteadOfInheritance) them - in to different pages as needed without any modification to the classes being needed.

Comment: Funny that [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/if-page-having-multiple-extensions-two-extensions-have-same-method-signature-bu) just got pinged by @[Community](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach, you can add it as inner class and access it:

```
class PaymentPlanController
{
    /*
     ...
     Amazing stuff
     ...
     ...
     ...
    */


    // Inner one
    public with sharing class LoanPaymentPlanRecurringTask {

    String frequency = null;

    public List<SelectOption> getFrequencyType(){
        List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Daily','Daily'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Weekly','Weekly'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Monthly','Monthly'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Yearly','Yearly'));
        return options;
    }
    public String getFrequency(){
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String frequency){
        this.frequency=frequency;
    }
}

}
```

And on visualforce page access it by creating instance in main controller.

Comment: It shows only one radio button and nothing else. Everything else on the VF page remains empty ? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Ya! you may have used it in different way. Access the inner class for the select radio button only. I hope you are not setting it as controller or extension.

Comment: public LoanPaymentPlanRecurringTask recurringTaskLPP {get; set;}
used above line in the controller and still it just displays one radio button nothing else. and the page is now   <apex:selectRadio value="{!recurringTaskLPP.frequency}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!recurringTaskLPP.frequencyType}"></apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

Answer (score 1):

In case the scenario is that you want to reuse either controller code or parts of Visualforce code across pages, you can make use of a visualforce component (`<apex:component />`). The component can have a controller of its own and will be reusable across pages.

See a similar example (for picklist) here:
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.nl/2011/05/updating-attributes-in-component.html